# Get ThemeResource textbox / richeditbox foreground and background color properties from code behind

Tags: c#, xaml, winui

Making a basic text editor with WinUI, MVVM. Stucked in default RichEditBox foreground and background color **viewmodel** properties based on selected theme, to show them in AppBar ColorPickerButtons.

Using `Application.Current.Resources[]`:

Tried different resource names and still not getting correct colors in dark theme (white foreground and whatever background color uses richeditbox). **They always show light theme colors**:

- `TextControlForegroundFocused` (that TextBox Class msdn page
  states it is "Text color when focused")
- `TextFillColorPrimary`
- `SystemControlBackgroundAltHighBrush`
- `SystemColorButtonFaceColor`
- `SystemColorButtonTextColor`

Same results using `new TextBox().Resources` as property value (TextBox because, again, msdn TextBox class page states that resources used by TextBox are shared with RichEditBox, among other controls. Same results using RichEditBox):

- `TextBoxForegroundThemeBrush`
- `TextBoxBackgroundThemeBrush`

So maybe the question is how to know what specific resource / themeresource names are used in specific control properties. I see resource names in resource xaml files are very descriptive but for now it is a mess for me. Also, I never see dark theme in those files, only Default, Light and HighContrast, and there are no colors matching dark theme, so it is evident that I am missing something (or many things :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the default style of `RichEditBox` controls. You can get the **ThemeResources's Keys**.

```xml
<Style TargetType="RichEditBox">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForeground}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackground}" />
    <Setter Property="SelectionHighlightColor" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlSelectionHighlightColor}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemePadding}" />
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{ThemeResource IsApplicationFocusVisualKindReveal}" />
    <Setter Property="ContextFlyout" Value="{StaticResource TextControlCommandBarContextFlyout}" />
    <Setter Property="SelectionFlyout" Value="{StaticResource TextControlCommandBarSelectionFlyout}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="RichEditBox">
                <Grid>

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">

                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlHeaderForegroundDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />

                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundFocused}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundFocused}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushFocused}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundFocused}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RequestedTheme">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Light" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                        </VisualStateGroup>

                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Foreground="{ThemeResource TextControlHeaderForeground}"
                        Margin="{ThemeResource RichEditBoxTopHeaderMargin}"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                        FontWeight="Normal"
                        TextWrapping="Wrap"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        Visibility="Collapsed"
                        x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy" />
                    <Border x:Name="BorderElement"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.RowSpan="1"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}"
                        MinWidth="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinWidth}"
                        MinHeight="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}" />
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}"
                        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                        VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}"
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                        IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}"
                        IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}"
                        IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}"
                        Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        IsTabStop="False"
                        ZoomMode="Disabled"
                        AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
                    <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Foreground="{ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForeground}"
                        Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        Text="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}"
                        TextAlignment="{TemplateBinding TextAlignment}"
                        TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}"
                        IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="DescriptionPresenter"
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Description}"
                        Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlDescriptionTextForegroundBrush}"
                        AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                        x:Load="False"/>

                </Grid>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

For example, you can override the `Background` when the control is focused like this.

```cs
App.Current.Resources["TextControlBackgroundFocused"] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.HotPink);
```